# Send String Msg between 2 .net applications (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, winapi, pinvoke, sendmessage

I want to send a string Message from .net Application A and Receive the message from the Application B and here's the code:

-------- Application A

```
Private Const RF_TESTMESSAGE As Integer = &HA123

Public Structure MyData
   Public M As String
   Public I As Integer
End Structure


Public Function SendTest() 
        Dim Data As New MyData
        Data.M = "QWERTY"
        Data.I = 15
        Dim P As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Data))
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Data, P, False)
        Dim Hdl As New IntPtr(11111) 'While 11111 is the WndHD for the application B for testing
        SendMessage(Hdl, RF_TESTMESSAGE, IntPtr.Zero, P)
End Function
```

------- Application B

```
Private Const RF_TESTMESSAGE As Integer = &HA123

Public Structure MyData
   Public M As String
   Public I As Integer
End Structure

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = RF_TESTMESSAGE Then
            Dim A = DirectCast(m.GetLParam(GetType(MyData)), MyData)

            MsgBox(A.M)
            MsgBox(A.I)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(m.LParam)

        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

The application B always receive the message, but unable to convert the point lParam to valid MyData Structure, and sometime raise access violation, sometime no error ....

Please advice.

Comment: The most straight forward way would be to use [`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx). A good article explaining this procedure can be found at [Simple Interprocess Communications using WM_COPYDATA](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Windows_Messages/Simple_Interprocess_Communication/article.asp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not properly marshalling the data between the two applications. You are allocating memory in one application, and then passing a pointer to that memory to a second application. But because application's have private memory spaces and cannot read each other's memory, that pointer is useless to the second application.

Depending on what it points to in *that* application's memory space, it might be triggering an access violation, or just not working properly.

Perhaps you're confused by the naming of the `AllocHGlobal` and `FreeHGlobal` functions. Contrary to what first impressions might suggest, they do not actually allocate and free *global* memory. At least not memory that is globally accessible to all processes running on a machine. The name comes from the Windows `HGLOBAL` data type, which used to mean exactly this back in the days of 16-bit Windows, where all applications did share a common memory space and could read each others' memory. But that is no longer the case in modern 32-bit Windows. The names were retained for backwards compatibility reasons. `HGLOBAL` and `HLOCAL` mean effectively the same thing nowadays. More on the nitty gritty details is available [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366596.aspx). But that's mostly a curiosity. You don't need to know and understand all of it to get the code working correctly.

The point is that all `AllocHGlobal` does is allocate memory from the process's default heap, readable only to that process. Hence the need to marshal the memory across processes, making it accessible from the other one receiving the message. Doing this manually is, of course, an option. But not a very good one. It's tricky to get right, and there's little point. Like Tim's comment hints at, the easier option is to use the [`WM_COPYDATA` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx), which does the marshalling for you. When you use this message, the data you want to share is packaged in a [`COPYDATASTRUCT` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649010.aspx).

You can keep most of your existing code to allocate memory, you just need to replace your custom `RF_TESTMESSAGE` window message with `WM_COPYDATA`. Sample code, including the necessary structure definition, is available over on the [pinvoke website](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/COPYDATASTRUCT.html).

Something like this (warning—untested and uncompiled):

```vb
Private Const WM_COPYDATA As Integer = &H004A

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure COPYDATASTRUCT 
   Public dwData As IntPtr
   Public cdData As Integer
   Public lpData As IntPtr
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure MyData
   Public M As String
   Public I As Integer
End Structure

Public Function SendTest() 
    ' Create your data structure, MyData, and fill it.
    Dim data As New MyData
    data.M = "QWERTY"
    data.I = 15
    Dim pData As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(data))
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, pData, False)

    ' Create the COPYDATASTRUCT you'll use to shuttle the data.
    Dim copy As New COPYDATASTRUCT
    copy.dwData = IntPtr.Zero
    copy.lpData = pData
    copy.cbData = Marshal.SizeOf(data)
    Dim pCopy As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(copy))
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(copy, pCopy, False)

    ' Send the message to the other application.
    SendMessage(New IntPtr(11111), WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, pCopy)

    ' Free the memory we allocated
    ' (This works because SendMessage is synchronous, and does not
    ' return until the other application has finished processing
    ' the data that you have sent it. That also means that the
    ' other application should not and cannot free the memory.
    ' If it needs it after processing the message, it needs to
    ' make a local copy.)
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pCopy)
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pData)
End Function
```

If you decide not to go the easy route using `WM_COPYDATA` and instead marshal the data yourself, you need to make sure to call the [`RegisterWindowMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947.aspx) function (if you are not doing so already in code I can't see) to ensure that the ID of your custom window message is unique.